# how to output the states of lstm gates in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I want to see the activation states of lstm gates, but it seems that it is not easy to get the gates states and output them to a file.

I can use "tf.Print" function like following in BasicLSTM:
`gate = tf.Print(gate, [sigmoid(gate)])`

But "tf.Print" displays this gate in terminal like:
`gate name : [0.5222222, 0.444444, 0.3333333, ...]`
I can not get all the values of this gate, just "...". And I must use redirectory to output them to files.

---

**Thanks for @ben, I can use `tf.Print(gate, [sigmoid(gate)], summarize=10000000)` to solve "...". But redirectory is also needed to output them to files.**

---

I also try to assign a name to the gate in BasicLSTM:
`gate = tf.identity(gate_tmp, "gate")`
then, I can get this tensor by name using 
`gate = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("model/RNN/while/BasicLSTMCell/gate:0")`
But when I `sess.run(gate)`
An error ocurred, "gate is not fetchable"

So I change "gate" to a variable.

`gate = tf.Variable(gate, trainable=False)`
But an new error ocurred, "All inputs to node model_1/Variable_1/Assign must be from the same frame."

So, how should I do to get the states of LSTM gates? And output them to a file?

Comment: How did you returned the gate tensor from the BasicLSTM module to your main app?? I am trying to change TF source code to return this tensor along with the new_h, new_state tuples but got too many errors.

Answer (score 0):

[tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print) supports a special parameter "summarize" to control the number of printed elements: E.g. you can use

```
tf.Print(gate, [sigmoid(gate)], summarize=10000000)
```

Comment: It is worked, but I want to output them to files. Any way else except redirectory?